# Two references to table in sqlite database android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to store match results in a database. I have a player table which contains an id, name password. Another table which stores matches. Then finally a Match participant table which will have an `id`, `player_id` (foreign key), `match_id` (foreign key) and a `score` which is an integer. I am trying to create the `Match` table so that it can reference two Match participants but I am unsure how to do this.

Code I have done to create tables

```
 myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                    + playerTableName
                    + " (Player_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            "UserName VARCHAR, Password VARCHAR, Experience INTEGER, Rating INTEGER);");

            myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                    + matchTableName
                    + "(Match_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            "? not sure here");");

            myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                    + participantTableName
                    + "(Participant_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                    "player_id INTEGER, match_id Integer," +
                    "FOREIGN KEY(player_id) REFERENCES "+ playerTableName+"(Player_id)," +
                    " FOREIGN KEY(match_id) REFERENCES "+ matchTableName+"(Match_id)," +
            " Score INTEGER);");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                + matchTableName
                + "(Match_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "Participant1_id integer, ");
                + "Participant2_id integer, ");
                + "FOREIGN KEY(Participant1_id) REFERENCES "+ participantTableName+"(Participant_id),"
                + "FOREIGN KEY(Participant2_id) REFERENCES "+ participantTableName+"(Participant_id)"
                + ");";
```

There's no problem at all in having two links to the same table. When you do your query to select or insert, be sure to save the correct ids in your table, and that will work.

Some notes:

- No need for the match_id in participant table. That will only duplicate the participants id from your match table. It's never good to have duplicate information in a SQL table, they could go out of sync, and constraints could become hell (when deleting). OR if you want to keep that match_id, then the two participant_ids in the match table are not needed.
- You should names all your primary ids `_id`, it's the usual good practice with `SQLite` (And I think in some cases, Android/SQLite will crash when it doesn't find them)